# iOS 10 How to animate UIBezierPath of UIVisualEffectView maskView

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode8, uibezierpath

I just updated to Xcode 8 and I had problem with Blur (UIVisualEffectView) on iOS 10, but I solve it. But after I fixed the blur layer mask second problem is appears, when I getting the reference of maskView from UIVisualEffectView and apply the new UIBezierPath nothing happens.

Code example:

```
-(void)prepareEffectView{

    //Frame
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;

    UIView *maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    maskView.layer.mask = ({ // This mask draws a rectangle and crops a circle inside it.

        UIBezierPath *maskLayerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [maskLayerPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:frame]];
        [maskLayerPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(self.btnScan.center.x, self.btnScan.center.y, 0, 0)]];
        [maskLayer setPath:maskLayerPath.CGPath];
        [maskLayerPath setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

        CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        mask.path     = maskLayerPath.CGPath;
        mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
        mask;
    });

    self.visualEffectView.maskView = maskView;
}


-(void)openAperture{

  //Blur layer
  CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
  CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.visualEffectView.maskView.layer.mask;


  //New path value
  UIBezierPath *maskLayerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
  [maskLayerPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:frame]];
  [maskLayerPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(58, 15, 66, 15)) cornerRadius:1]];
  [maskLayer setPath:maskLayerPath.CGPath];


  //Animation
  CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
  animation.delegate = self;
  animation.duration = 0.44;
  animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
  animation.fromValue = (id)maskLayer.path;
  animation.toValue = (id)maskLayerPath.CGPath;
  [maskLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Apple Note About VisualEffectView issue on iOS 10
>
> Transitions are tough in this realm, as maskView is the only way to
>   ensure that the effect works, but maskView also isn't animatable.
>
> https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/184810#184810

The only the way to use "CAShapeLayer" as a mask is to apply your shape to UIView.layer.mask and then put it to UIVisualEffectView.maskView.

The maskView of UIVisualEffectView isn't animatable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I tried to do next: (Swift code)

```
visualEffectView.layer.mask = maskView.layer.mask
```

instead of `visualEffectView.mask = maskView`

If so, path animation works fine, but then **blur effect is gone**.

If you find a solution, please update the post.